# How to prevent the table and image elements from moving when resizing browser window [REPOST]

Tags: html, css, layout, resize

I previously posted a question and edited it but the edited version does not show the correct code so I'm reposting it. When I resize my browser window, the images seem to go out of the "box" or it's container. I'm a beginner at coding and I know it's much better if I use div instead of table, but this is for practice purposes (and also, I need it for a school project and I figured that's how I want to use the table element). Anyways, please help me figure out what to do/ how to fix the code.

EDIT: Looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXSrD.jpg) when I resize.

```css
.post {
  padding: 3em 3em 1em 3em;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: solid 1px rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.3);
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  position: relative;
}

.post>header {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.3);
  left: -3em;
  margin: -3em 0 3em 0;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% + 6em);
}

.post>header .title {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 3.75em 3em 3.3em 3em;
}

.post>header .title h2 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.post>header .title> :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
}

.group {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<article class="post">
  <header>
    <div class="title">
      <h2><a href="#">Favorite Books</a></h2>
    </div>
  </header>


  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" alt="#" class="image" /> </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" alt="#" class="image" /> </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" alt="#" class="image" /> </a>
      </td>
  </tr>                          
  </table>
  
 </article>
```

Comment: "Tables are for data not layout" That's a motto I try to live by.

Comment: I know, I know. But as I said above, it's just for practice purposes. I have no other uses for tables (and it's a requirement for a school project to use it) so I just decided to make a "bookshelf" type of thing with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add

```
width: 700px;
```

To your post class:

```css
.post {
  padding: 3em 3em 1em 3em;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: solid 1px rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.3);
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
}

.post>header {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.3);
  left: -3em;
  margin: -3em 0 3em 0;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% + 6em);
}

.post>header .title {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 3.75em 3em 3.3em 3em;
}

.post>header .title h2 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.post>header .title> :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
}

.group {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<article class="post">
  <header>
    <div class="title">
      <h2><a href="#">Favorite Books</a></h2>
    </div>
  </header>


  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" alt="#" class="image" /> </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" alt="#" class="image" /> </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" alt="#" class="image" /> </a>
      </td>
  </tr>                          
  </table>
  
 </article>
```

Comment: there's supposed to be like 3-4 images in a row but when i add that to td, the images just align in one column.

Comment: Ok now they are, i didn't understand ^^

Answer (score 0):

Just update the image css

```
.image {
  display: block;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work, and it distorts the sizes of the images.

Comment: please look at the edit i added on the post, i linked an image of how it looks like

Answer (score 0):

As you already admit that the html structure is not good (better say should be avoided), still I am trying to introduce a different approach.

## css

```
td{
 /*append this style along yours*/
 height:200px;
 width:200px;
 display:block;
}
```

## html

```
<td style="background-image: url('YOUR IMAGE URL');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-attachment: fixed;background-position: center;" onclick="javascript:window.location = 'YOUR HREF OF OLD A TAG'">
    &nbsp;
  </td>
```

**YOUR IMAGE URL** is your images' absolute urls
**YOUR HREF OF OLD A TAG** the url's where the it should be redirected on click

Comment: please look at the edit i added on the post, i linked an image of how it looks like